# Use GROUP BY and ORDER BY within a UNION query

Tags: mysql

I have a pretty basic chat app with two tables: `Users`, and `Messages`. Both tables do what they say on the tin :) When a user sends a message to another user, I record both the `userID` (the message sender) and `userIDReceived` (the message recipient) on the `Messages` table.

The relevant data are as follows:

```
table : Users
+-------+-----------+
|userID | username  |
+-------+-----------+
|    1  |    John   |
|    2  |    Mary   |
|    3  |    Jeff   |
|    4  |    Bill   |
|    5  |    Bob    |
+-------+-----------+

table : Messages
+---------+-----------+--------------+------------===----+
|messageID|    userID |userIDReceived|        created    |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    1    |    1      |        2     |2024-02-01 19:55:37|
|    2    |    1      |        2     |2024-02-01 17:20:10|
|    3    |    2      |        3     |2024-02-01 19:27:18|
|    4    |    3      |        1     |2024-01-16 17:46:57|
|    5    |    3      |        1     |2024-01-26 02:34:44|
+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
```

I have normalised these tables so that user data is stored in the `Users` table, while message data is stored in the `Messages` table. What I am trying to do is group all messages sent and received by specific users (by `userID`) so that only that last sent and/or received message is returned.

Here is an example of my query where `userID` 1 is trying to get the last message sent to him by any other user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'sent' AS direction, u.userID, u.username, MAX(m.messageID), MAX(m.created), m.message
FROM Messages m
LEFT JOIN Users u
ON m.userIDReceived = u.userID
WHERE m.userID = 1
GROUP BY m.userIDReceived 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'received' AS direction, u.userID, u.username, MAX(m.messageID), MAX(m.created), m.message
FROM Messages m
LEFT JOIN Users u
ON m.userID = u.userID
WHERE m.userIDReceived = 1
GROUP BY m.userID;
```

The query works, however the returned "message" value is always incorrect - it seems to always show the first ever message sent between two users. I cannot seem to be able to apply `MAX()` to the message column (because it's a text field so trying to order it is nonsenical), or `ORDER BY` to returned dates in order to show the correct message value.

```
I want my result to look like this:
+---------+-----------+--------------+------------===----+---------+
|messageID|    userID |username|        created          |message  |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+---------+
|sent     |    1      |        2     |2024-02-01 19:55:37|Hey there|
|sent     |    1      |        2     |2024-02-01 17:20:10|Hi       |
|sent     |    2      |        3     |2024-02-01 19:27:18|How      |
|received |    3      |        1     |2024-01-16 17:46:57|Yeah good|
|received |    3      |        1     |2024-01-26 02:34:44|Cool     |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+---------+
```

Note that the column `messageID` isn't really required to be returned; I was just trying to use it to solve this query problem.

Also, the server version is 5.7.44-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server - (GPL)

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `SELECT VERSION();` output? Also see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: @Akina Hi, it's 5.7.44-cll-lve

Comment: @Akina Thanks for that link. Would it be OK if I added some database rows and expected output?

Comment: It is recommended to add some sample data and expected output and please make it in text form, not as image.

Comment: *Would it be OK if I added some database rows and expected output?* Add: CREATE TABLE for both tables, INSERT INTO, 3-4 rows for `users` and 1-5 rows per user for `messages`, desired output for this data. The code must be in code-formatted text form (separate lines with triple backticks before and after the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that subquery returns the entire row with the maximum `created` timestamp for each conversation, then join this result back to the `Messages` table to get the actual message text:

```
WITH LastMessage AS (
    SELECT userID, userIDReceived, MAX(created) AS MaxCreated
    FROM Messages
    WHERE userID = 1 OR userIDReceived = 1
    GROUP BY userID, userIDReceived
)
SELECT 'sent' AS direction, u.userID, u.username, lm.MaxCreated, m.message
FROM LastMessage lm
JOIN Messages m ON lm.userID = m.userID AND lm.userIDReceived = m.userIDReceived AND lm.MaxCreated = m.created
LEFT JOIN Users u ON m.userIDReceived = u.userID
WHERE m.userID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'received' AS direction, u.userID, u.username, lm.MaxCreated, m.message
FROM LastMessage lm
JOIN Messages m ON lm.userID = m.userID AND lm.userIDReceived = m.userIDReceived AND lm.MaxCreated = m.created
LEFT JOIN Users u ON m.userID = u.userID
WHERE m.userIDReceived = 1;
```

## Edit

> OP tells that his MySQL version is 5.7, i.e. CTE is not available.

Use subquery instead of CTE.

```
SELECT 'sent' AS direction, u.userID, u.username, lm.MaxCreated, m.message
FROM (
    SELECT userID, userIDReceived, MAX(created) AS MaxCreated
    FROM Messages
    WHERE userID = 1 OR userIDReceived = 1
    GROUP BY userID, userIDReceived
) AS lm
JOIN Messages m ON lm.userID = m.userID AND lm.userIDReceived = m.userIDReceived AND lm.MaxCreated = m.created
LEFT JOIN Users u ON m.userIDReceived = u.userID
WHERE m.userID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'received' AS direction, u.userID, u.username, lm.MaxCreated, m.message
FROM (
    SELECT userID, userIDReceived, MAX(created) AS MaxCreated
    FROM Messages
    WHERE userID = 1 OR userIDReceived = 1
    GROUP BY userID, userIDReceived
) AS lm
JOIN Messages m ON lm.userID = m.userID AND lm.userIDReceived = m.userIDReceived AND lm.MaxCreated = m.created
LEFT JOIN Users u ON m.userID = u.userID
WHERE m.userIDReceived = 1;
```

Modified from > *Here is an example of my query where userID 1 is trying to get the last message sent to him by any other user:*

```
SELECT 'sent' AS direction, m1.userID, u.username, m1.messageID, m1.created, m1.message
FROM Messages m1
JOIN Users u ON m1.userIDReceived = u.userID
WHERE m1.userID = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Messages m2
    WHERE m2.userID = m1.userID
    AND m2.userIDReceived = m1.userIDReceived
    AND m2.created > m1.created
)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'received' AS direction, m1.userID, u.username, m1.messageID, m1.created, m1.message
FROM Messages m1
JOIN Users u ON m1.userID = u.userID
WHERE m1.userIDReceived = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Messages m2
    WHERE m2.userID = m1.userID
    AND m2.userIDReceived = m1.userIDReceived
    AND m2.created > m1.created
);
```

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation Not your fault, I added the version to the question after you provided your answer :)

Comment: Oh wow, that seems to work! I'll do some more testing and report back with the results, but thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: Hey as far as I can tell your query works brilliantly, but I'm curious about the difference between the two versions you posted in the edit? They both seem to return the same results - why did you post two? Is one more performant than the other?

Comment: My answer is on the edit that not to use CTE and I just modified your query above the question, because it may look you understand how it works, so its up to you what do you prefer to use.